# Spring Boot caching feature doesn't require spring-boot-starter-cache

Tags: spring-boot

When you're trying to use spring boot caching feature using `@Cacheable`,
you don't need the starter module `spring-boot-starter-cache` which is called "Spring Cache Abstraction" in Spring Initializr.

```
// very basic gradle project setup on spring initializr, with zero dependencies
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

```java
public record Student(String name, int age) {
}

@Repository
public class StudentRepo {

    @Cacheable("cache")
    public Student get() {
        System.out.println("No cache");
        return new Student("Fred", 18);
    }

}

// in any spring component
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void init() {
    System.out.println(repo.get());
    System.out.println(repo.get());
    System.out.println(repo.get());
    System.out.println(repo.get());
    System.out.println(repo.get());
}
```

This is the result.

```
No cache
Student[name=Fred, age=18]
Student[name=Fred, age=18]
Student[name=Fred, age=18]
Student[name=Fred, age=18]
Student[name=Fred, age=18]
```

Obviously cache worked. It's probably concurrent hash map, according to the document.

I figured out how this was possible. Following to the dependencies in maven repository, `spring-boot-starter-cache` gives you:

```
org.springframework » spring-context-support
org.springframework.boot » spring-boot-starter
```

We already have `spring-boot-starter`, so digging into `spring-context-support`,

```
org.springframework » spring-beans
org.springframework » spring-context
org.springframework » spring-core
```

Well, they look so familiar. Because these are exactly what `spring-boot-starter` already has.

Basically starter modules are transitive dependencies. But even so, I don't see what `spring-boot-starter-cache` exactly does for activating cache features, because it worked only with `spring-boot-starter` anyway.

Now what I wonder is: Why should I add `spring-boot-starter-cache`?

Comment: Hi @Djuno, who said you had to use `spring-boot-starter-cache`?

Comment: Okay, so I guess, you meant the guide from Spring about caching. I've looked up that artifact too. There's nothing more there. No configs and no code. So I guess it's some kind of a placeholder for future developments that may differ from the standard starter artifact.

Comment: A small hint: you don't need that much explanation for the question, if you'd shrink it together to "works without the cache-starter", the question would attract more people's attention, because shorter. I think I make an edit for you.

Comment: It "works"  but only for no-cache or using maps. It will not work with a proper cache like EhCache, Caffeine etc. as support for those implementations is in `spring-context-support`. The same for a transactional aware cache, that is also part of the `spring-context-support`. So is "works" but nor really as it isn't a full and proper caching implementation that is in use. Now there might ofcourse also be something else that pulls in `spring-context-support` for its use (like using java-mail, or scheduling with Quartz) which makes it available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It "works"  but only for no-cache or using maps. The only support available in the `spring-context` dependency is the [`NoOpCacheManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/support/NoOpCacheManager.html) and the [`SimpleCacheManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/support/SimpleCacheManager.html) (using `Map`).

It will not work with a proper cache like [EhCache](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/ehcache/EhCacheCacheManager.html), [Caffeine](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/caffeine/CaffeineCacheManager.html) etc. as support for those implementations is part of `spring-context-support`. The same for a transactional aware cache, that is also part of `spring-context-support`.

So it "works" but nor really as it isn't a full and proper caching implementation that is in use.

Now there might ofcourse also be something else that pulls in `spring-context-support` for its use (like using java-mail, or scheduling with Quartz) which makes it available.

The same is mentioned in the Spring Boot Reference Guide in the [caching section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.caching).

> Use the `spring-boot-starter-cache` “Starter” to quickly add basic caching dependencies. The starter brings in `spring-context-support`. If you add dependencies manually, you must include `spring-context-support` in order to use the JCache, EhCache 2.x, or Caffeine support.

Comment: Ah, so that was what I missed. `spring-context-support` itself has some more things inside the package including a few cache supports that you've said. Thanks!